# Is there any way to have a max height in cluetip

Tags: jquery

I am using [jquery tooltip plugin cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#options) that is small or very big depending on using.  I see there is a way to set height to either "auto" or `fixed`.

But I want an altered version of "auto" height where it's automatically growing to maxheight and then becomes fixed . This will make short tooltips become short and very long tooltips have a max cutoff point.

Is this possible as I don't find this in the API.

Comment: select the generated tip and give it a `max-height` style?

Comment: @Chad - i don't understand your response . . can you please clarify or give more detail

Comment: Just saying see how the plugin generates tooltips, what HTML does it output. You may be able to select the outputted `div` for example and do something like `.css('max-height', '200px')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this in your CSS:

```
.ui-cluetip-header, .ui-cluetip-content {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 4em;
}
```

it will set a max height to your cluetip body and a scrollbar will appear when the content doesn't fit into the cluetip body

Comment: I wound up doing this but your answer led me in the right direction:  <style type="text/css">
        #cluetip-inner {
            overflow: auto;
            max-height: 43em;
        }
    </style>